# Why does underscore.reduce acts differently in these two cases?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I was trying to flatten an object that has two objects in it, so I did the following:

```
var underscore = require('underscore');
var obj = { a: {x:1}, b: {y:2}};
underscore.reduce(obj, underscore.extend, {});
```

Unexpectedly, the output that I've got was:

```
{ 
   '0': 'b',
   x: 1,
   a: { x: 1 },
   b: { y: 2 },
   y: 2 
}
```

So then I've tried to wrap `extend` in a function:

```
underscore.reduce(obj, function(memo, o) {
   return underscore.extend(memo, o);
}, {});
```

And got the expected result:

```
{ x: 1, y: 2 }
```

Why is there any difference? `reduce` expected as the 2nd argument a function that gets two arguments and returns one, and it gets it in both cases. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `reduce` expected as the 2nd argument a function that gets two arguments and returns one...

Not according to [the documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce). Underscore passes the iterator *four*, not two, arguments:

> The iterator is passed four arguments: the `memo`, then the `value` and `index` (or `key`) of the iteration, and finally a reference to the entire `list`.

Consequently, you end up calling `extend` (on the first pass) like this:

```
underscore.extend({}, {x: 1}, 'a', obj)
```

and then the second pass

```
underscore.extend({/*...stuff...*/}, {y: 2}, 'b', obj)
```

The reason the object has a `'0': 'b'` attribute is that strings extend into an object containing attributes like  `'<index>': '<char>'`.  This is because `_.extend` runs a `for...in...` loop on each argument (except the first) and the keys found by doing that to a string are the character indexes (from `0` to `str.length - 1`).

Comment: Got it. So basically I did `underscore.extend({}, {x:1}, 'a', obj);`

Comment: @Gil: Yup, on the first pass. :-)

Comment: The string `"a"`, when looped over with a `for...in...` loop (which is how `_.extend` works) emits exactly one key - the index of the only character in the string (`0`).  A longer string would extend with, for example, `'abc'` -> `{'0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c'}`.

Comment: @AaronDufour: Excellent, thanks -- I figured it was something like that, appreciate your taking the time to explain it. I'm intrigued to see that effect on `for-in` on a string... (Feel free to edit that into the answer, btw, if you're of a mind. SO is about collaboration, one of the reasons I pitch in here.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I always forget about editing, which is why I commented.  Done!